# How to get list of available nodes (of Yarn cluster) in application Master?

Tags: java, hadoop-yarn, hadoop2

I am writing a yarn-application. The application-master should launch this application on given number of distinct hosts (Host-names are not provided). For this I will need list of nodes present in cluster. How I can get this list in application-master so that I can request application container on those machines?

Comment: Did you checked **/etc/hosts** and **$HADOOP_HOME/etc/hadoop/slaves** ??

Comment: It's not going to work. I got a better way of doing this.

Comment: I'm sorry can you tell how you solved this issue?

Comment: I used YarnClient APIs for this. It requires hadoop/yarn configuration files in class path.

Comment: What exact method, you've used to get clusted nodes list, and which part of YARN application invoked this code (Yarn client initializing part, or ApplicationMaster)?

Comment: I used getNodeReports method as described at https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/yarn/client/api/YarnClient.html in application master.